# Find visual studio version on which the exe was build, from the MFC exe

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I have a exe which is made in MFC. I want to find out on which visual studio version the exe was build.

Answer (score 1):

Try CFFExplorer from http://www.ntcore.com/. This small program tells you a lot of interesting things about a windows executable and does quite a good job guessing wich development environement has been use to create it.